# Why I can't call this method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a method signature here:

```
.h

-(void)addToArray
```

And I want to use it here:

```
.m 

-(void)viewDidLoad{
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[array addToArray];
}

-(void)addToArray{
//some code here…
}
```

The problem is that when I do [array addToArray]; it returns to me a message that says "Instance method '-addToArray' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"
How can I solve it?

Comment: Well, of course, `addToArray` is not a method of `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you do `[array somemethod]` ..it will look for the method in that array data type class( that is in `NSMutableArray` class.

when you have a method in your own class.and it is not a category...then you must call

```
[self somemethod]
```

this way it will look in the class that is in which you are calling the method.

Comment: OK. The code is OK. But it doesn't work well, when I run it Xcode stop the app and returns to me: "Thread 1: Program recived signal"EXC_BAD_ACCESS""

Comment: debug your code using breakpoints,,..if you don't know what it is...then check some youtube tutorials.. debugging will help you a lot in future..after you see the line where it crashes.. post that line as an update to your question and i will help.

Comment: Ok. Thank you Shubhank so much. Now I don't have time, but tomorrow I will. I'm going to see some videos and read something about debugging, and then I will post it here. Thank you.

Comment: So the debugger output says : "Single stepping until exit from function objc_msgSend, 
which has no line number information." at the line [array addToArray];

Answer (score 3):

**Change to:**

.h

```
-(void)addObjectsToArray:(NSMutableArray*)a;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     [self addObjectsToArray:array];
}
- (void)addObjectsToArray:(NSMutableArray*)a {
     //some code here…
     [a addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Example String Object"]]; // example way to add objects to the array
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Shubhank's answer is indeed correct, however if you want to accomplish what you'd initially described, that is have the have the NSMutableArray instance respond to your method, you can achieve that through the use of categories. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html

This blog details adding a category to NSArray and/or NSMutableArray.
http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/macsploitation/extending-classes-in-objectivec-with-categories-27447

Answer (score -1):

In your m file, try doing this: #import "whatever its called.h" if you haven't yet. If you provide more code I can give more help, but I hope this helps.